# Combining Dictionary and writing into a text file and reading again as dictionary?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am hitting into a link and getting a json file per hit. Then I am writing the data into a text file. But when I want to read it again I want to read it as dictionary.How can I do that.

```
def url_seq(limit=5):
    for i in range(limit):
        link = 'http:...x={}'.format(i)
    yield link

def json_seq(link):
    for text in link:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(text) as url:
            data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
            yield data['data']

open('data.txt', 'w').close()
for item in json_seq(url_seq(limit=100)):
        with open('data.txt', 'a') as f:
            json.dump(item, f)
            f.write(',')
```

The out put file is like that,
    `{'x': 0.0, 'y': -7.462079426179981},{'x': 1.0, 'y':-5.300602624446985},{'x': 2.0, 'y': 1.4418651159990272}, ... ,`

But I want to read it as a dictionary. So that I can put them to a pandas dataframe for analysis.

The following code gives me a list, is there any way to read it to a dictionary. I am bit new in Python, Sorry if I mean some thing non-pythonic. Thanks in advance.

```
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
lines = f.read().split(',')
```

Comment: If you save it as JSON, you can load it as JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend putting all your individual data items in a list, and saving *that* as a JSON file.

```
data = [x for x in json_seq(url_seq(limit=100))]
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Later, you may read the JSON file with `pd.read_json`:

```
df = pd.read_json('data.json')
```

---

If you really want to save memory, add opening and closing braces in between the `item` writes.

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write('[')
    for item in json_seq(url_seq(limit=100)):
        f.write(json.dumps(item) + ',')
    f.write(']')
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to save the memory and did not wanted save the data first into a list but to save the data directly in to text file because the data will be really large.

Comment: @DataPoliceInc. See edit. Also, if you are planning to read it in as a pandas dataframe, you could just write it as a single JSON, I don't see what the problem would be.

Comment: @COLDSPEED  Now I get it. Thank you a lot.